# when I use heroku live hosting url data not found but For localhost:5000 it's working, what's wrong with this heroku url?

Tags: heroku

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnbVE.png)
This is my localhost:5000/bikes/_id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tb4x.png)
This is the heroku url/bikes/_id

**but when I use this (heroku url/bikes)url then it's work**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB0oR.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

it might be that you get a cached result from the heroku url/bikes/_id
make sure you refresh the content using developer tools or postman